# dynamic keys in jsdoc typedef

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Is it possible to have dynamic keys (prop names) in a jsdoc typedef? I'm imagining this would look something like the example below (which does not work).

```
@typedef {Object} Foo
@property {string} bar
@property {*} *
```

Passing properties not listed in the typedef `e.g. {baz: 0}` makes typescript upset with something like,

> Argument of type '{ bar: string; baz: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'baz' does not exist in type 'Foo'

---

Using the method proposed by @jcalz `Object.<string, *>` seems closer to the ideal output but resulted in a strange output

```
@typedef {Object} Foo
@property {number} bar
@property {Object.<string, *>}
```

output:

```
type Foo = {
    bar: number;
    (Missing): {
        [x: string]: any;
    };
}
```

Comment: Maybe use something like `Object.<string, *>` instead of `Object`, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript#type)?

Comment: @jcalz, I wasn't able to make that work. I added the result to the post

Comment: Sorry, I've never really used JSDoc before.  I was suggesting replacing `Object` in the first line with `Object.<string, *>`, and that works to add an index signature, but it breaks when you add `bar`. The only thing I have seen that works is `/**@typedef { {[k: string]: any, bar: string } } Foo */`, but that's basically just using TypeScript type syntax instead of JSDoc.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use normal TS syntax in JSDOC.

See next example:

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {Record<string, string> & {bar:string}} arg
 */
const foo = (arg) => {}
```

You can even use utility types:

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {Partial<{age:number}>} arg 
 */
const partial = (arg) => { }
```

You can find more utils [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)